# Nginx redirect to dynamic path

Tags: nginx

**Background**
I have two instances of a web application which I want accessible at `mydomain.com/` and `mydomain.com/staging/`. I have configured nginx to proxy requests to the proper instance depending on the path, but when a link is clicked in the staging instance, the path (in the HTML) refers to the non-staging application.

**What I have**
I want to configure nginx to proxy requests to the staging environment whenever an http request is made with referrer `mydomain.com/staging/...`. I have this much working.

**What I need**
I need to redirect the request to the proper /staging url. I cannot figure out how to get (`example.com/<all this>`) the path out of the requested url and append it to my /staging path for redirection. Here is the relevant portion of my config.

```
location @puma {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;

  # if mydomain.com/products/1 is requested with a /staging referrer
  # I need to redirect to /staging/products/1 instead of always /staging/

  if ($http_referer ~* /.*\.com/staging$ ) {
    set $request_url /staging/; 
    return 301 $request_url;
  }
  proxy_pass http://puma_production;
}
```

Comment: Did you consider the Nginx sub_filter option instead of proxying? It could be a far neater way to (conditionally) rewrite URLs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

Comment: isn't it what this post is about ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671699/how-to-handle-redirect-response-properly-when-using-nginx-as-proxy-server-djang

Comment: Make everything easier on yourself; use a subdomain rather than a directory.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the ability to create a subdomain without going through levels of approval. This was the quickest way to do it without opening other ports or making dns changes.

Comment: Well then you could fix your application to correctly set prefix to urls when it served from subfolder.

Comment: I was hoping the application code could be independent of the environment it is running in but it looks like I will end up going that route. Thanks for the help.